# How does BERT utilize TPU memories?

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model, google-cloud-tpu, tpu, bert-language-model

[README](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/README.md#out-of-memory-issues) in the Google's BERT repo says, even a single sentence of length 512 can not sit in a 12 GB Titan X for the BERT-Large model.

But in the BERT paper, it says 64 TPU chips are used to train BERT-Large
with a maximum length 512 and batch size 256. How could they fit a >256x larger batch into only 171x more memory?

From another point of view, we can compare these two configurations in a memory-usage-per-sample basis:

- TPU: Assume TPUv3 is used in pre-training, the total TPU memory is 32 GB/chip * 64 chips = 2048 GB. According to the paper, a batch size of 256 with maximum length 512 works well in this configuration, which means **8 GB memory is able to hold a single sample.** Furthermore, memory usage per sample will reduce to only 4 GB if GPUv2 is used.
- GPU: **A 12 GB Titan X can not hold even a single sample of length 512**.

Why is memory consumption on GPUs much larger? Does this mean memory consumption on TPUs is optimized way better than that on GPUs?

Comment: How do you figure out the batch size is 256x larger?

Comment: The BERT paper says batch size is 256. And the BERT README says available batch size of Titan X is 0 (i.e.: less than 1). So it is more than 256x larger.

Comment: Maybe the original description is hard to follow, so I revised it into a memory-usage-per-sample basis. Hope this time I've made myself clearer.

Comment: it is 16 GB/chip (8GB/core).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to the advanced compiler that comes with TPU and optimized for tensorflow ops. As the [readme - out-of-memory issues](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/README.md#out-of-memory-issues) in BERT says,

> The major use of GPU/TPU memory during DNN training is caching the intermediate activations in the forward pass that are necessary for efficient computation in the backward pass.

However, in the TPU compiling, a special [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/overview) (domain-specific compiler for linear algebra that optimizes TensorFlow computations) instruction called [fusion](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools)

> can merge multiple instructions from different TensorFlow operations into a single computation. The TensorFlow operation corresponding to the root instruction in the fusion is used as the namespace of the fusion operation.

On the other side, running on the GPU with vanilla TF basically has no (or very limited) optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I heard it's also possible to turn on XLA compiler on GPU (e.g.: see https://medium.com/tensorflow/pushing-the-limits-of-gpu-performance-with-xla-53559db8e473). If this answer is true, does it mean there is a chance to fit sample(s) of length 512 into a 12 GB GPU by enabling XLA? Is it worth a try?

Comment: Yes, that is actually worth a try. I have heard that enabling xla on GPU can lead to 2x of memory reduction. But I don't have personal experience. One note is that you might get some quality loss if you train with a significant smaller batch size on GPU.

Comment: Things are weird. I tried BERT on my local GPU, a GTX 1080Ti with 11 GB memory. I managed to run 36 samples of length 128 with BERT-Base, which is larger than a batch size of 32 with a 12 GB Titan X as mentioned in BERT README; but failed to run as few as 2 samples of length 64 with BERT-Large (a Titan X can hold 12 such samples!).

Comment: I'm working on the XLA compiler, but no progress yet. BERT-Large on GTX 1080 Ti is really weird.